# Need Batch script in windows to upload files to a particular ftp location

Tags: windows, batch-file, ftp

I have several backup files in a location, say `C:\backup_folder\...`
Now I need a batch script (`.bat`), so that all files under `C:\backup_folder\*.zip` will be moved to a particular FTP location (`ftp.mysite.com`).

Also, if the file already exists on the FTP site, they must be overwritten with the new file... Can anyone show me a script that performs these backups?

Answer (score 2):

The trick with automated file xfer with Windows (for me at least) has always been using the correct commandline upload tool.  For ME, when I've wanted a shell-scriptable tool, that usually ends up being rsync from cygwin.  But since you asked about Windows batch with FTP (as opposed to a safer, more reliable solution, you might want to try using a Windows build of [wput](http://wput.sourceforge.net/)

Since you want to overwrite the file each time, you would use the -u (re-upload) option.  I found wput supported most of the FTP options I wanted, and should handle this job.  Although I absolutely agree with your desire to always re-upload the entire file, you CAN set it for a few optimizations that you might find handy if you're uploading over a slow link, like using a timestamp comparison to decide if you don't need to upload (-N).  Another option backup scripts MAY want is to remove your source file after a successful upload (-R option).

I just feel it's wise to point out that FTP isn't nearly as reliable a protocol as *I* would want in a backup script ... but your desire to always re-upload the file(s) is a good one.